# Rotate GeoTiff but maintain georeference

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I'm currently trying to 'cheat' a GeoTiff by rotating the image but keeping the georeference the same, I.E. I just want the actual visual image rotated.

Currently I'm reading in the image using rasterio and clipping it using the mask method. When I print the shape of the output image from mask I get `(1, 32, 32)`.

I then run:

```
out_image = transform.rotate(out_image, 90).astype(np.float32)
```

and still get `(1, 32, 32)` when printing the size.

However when I write out the GeoTiff and look at the image I only get a band of pixels rather than the rotated image as shown below:

Original:
[image: Original]

Rotated & Clipped:
[image: Rotated]

Why is it giving me just a band of pixels?

---

After Ipdudley's comment:

```
def create_crop(raster):
    affine = raster.affine
    point_x, point_y, radius = get_blob_point(raster)
    out_image, out_transform = mask(raster,
                                    [get_point_crop_polygon(Point(affine * (point_x, point_y)), radius)],
                                    crop=True)
    out_meta = raster.meta.copy()

    print(out_image.shape)

    out_image = np.rot90(out_image, k=1)

    print(out_image.shape)

    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                     "height": out_image.shape[1],
                     "width": out_image.shape[2],
                     "transform": out_transform})

    with rasterio.open("test.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are only getting a single line of pixels, perhaps you could post more of the code that is producing this result?

However this can be easily done with the [numpy.rot90](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) function. Here's with gdal / numpy:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

dataset = gdal.Open("/path/to/image", gdal.GA_Update)

# Get desired band
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

array = band.ReadAsArray()

# k is how many times the array is to be rotated (anti-clockwise)
rotated = np.rot90(band, k=1)

# write new data to band
band.WriteArray(rotated)

band = dataset = None
```

Comment: Edited my post with my code, with your answer I then get `ValueError: Source shape is inconsistent with given indexes`

Comment: I now also get back `(32, 1, 32)` for the shape

Comment: Hey @CiaranEvans, I think it's rotating the wrong axes, so maybe try fiddling that, i.e., numpy.rot90(m, k=1, axes=(1, 2)).

Comment: @AlexLeith That's brilliant thanks, sorted out the issue with the line of pixels, something so obvious now I think of it! Thanks again! - Also managed to keep the georeferencing of the original GeoTiff too!